# aAAVE (Atoken) accidently transferred from Metamask wallet to exchange AAVE wallet - HELP PLEASE!

Tags: erc-20, metamask, etherscan, aave

Really hoping someone here can help.

I have AAVE being used as collateral on AAVEV2 as I borrowed some USDC at very low LTV. I use metamask to connect to AAVE and in my wallet you can see aAAVE (interest beaing atoken) and normal AAVE. I mistakingly sent 10 aAAVE instead of normal AAVE to coinbase exchange AAVE wallet. See on etherscan below.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbc19fc4884f8c8ab1650bfa886e37f5d621805e22b476dfdcad0688371fa69df

The transaction was completed and I now presume my aAAVE tokens stuck in my coinbase AAVE wallet as it was received but naturally doesnt show up in AAVE wallet.

My question, is what can I do if anything??
I have sent request to support at coinbase but suspect they will take forever to respond. Is there anything I can do to get coins back?

Also, why when aAAVE was collateral, would I be allowed to send direct from Metamask to coinbase in 1st place i fit was collaterized?

many thanks in advance for any help.

D

Comment: They are developing some service to recover unsupported tokens read this article https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/trading-and-funding/sending-or-receiving-cryptocurrency/unsupported-crypto-recovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mistakingly sent 10 aAAVE instead of normal AAVE to coinbase exchange

This is a support question for Coinbase. Coinbase is a private venture and we do not know what they can or they cannot do.

> Also, why when aAAVE was collateral, would I be allowed to send direct from Metamask to coinbase in 1st place i fit was collaterized?

Because of how ERC-20 standard works, this cannot be prevented either.